# Error while the first sight generation in Jekyll on Windows

Tags: windows, jekyll, github-pages

I've just installed Jekyll 3.5.0 on Windows 10 using [this instruction](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/windows/).

I've successfully run `jekyll new my_blog` and my blog folder looks like

```
kontiky@DESKTOP-GRQ069N:~/my_blog$ ls
404.html  about.md  _config.yml  Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  index.md  _posts  vendor
```

but then I call `jekyll build` inside `my_blog` I see these warning and error messages

```
Deprecation: The 'gems' configuration option has been renamed to 'plugins'. Please update your config file accordingly.
/home/kontiky/my_blog/vendor/bundle/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/root.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Sass::ROOT_DIR
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/root.rb:6: warning: previous definition of ROOT_DIR was here
/home/kontiky/my_blog/vendor/bundle/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:23: warning: already initialized constant Sass::Util::RUBY_VERSION_COMPONENTS
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:23: warning: previous definition of RUBY_VERSION_COMPONENTS was here
/home/kontiky/my_blog/vendor/bundle/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:28: warning: already initialized constant Sass::Util::RUBY_ENGINE
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:28: warning: previous definition of RUBY_ENGINE was here
/home/kontiky/my_blog/vendor/bundle/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:867: warning: already initialized constant Sass::Util::CHARSET_REGEXP
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:867: warning: previous definition of CHARSET_REGEXP was here
/home/kontiky/my_blog/vendor/bundle/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:869: warning: already initialized constant Sass::Util::UTF_8_BOM
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:869: warning: previous definition of UTF_8_BOM was here
/home/kontiky/my_blog/vendor/bundle/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:870: warning: already initialized constant Sass::Util::UTF_16BE_BOM
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:870: warning: previous definition of UTF_16BE_BOM was here
/home/kontiky/my_blog/vendor/bundle/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:871: warning: already initialized constant Sass::Util::UTF_16LE_BOM
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:871: warning: previous definition of UTF_16LE_BOM was here
/home/kontiky/my_blog/vendor/bundle/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:1151: warning: already initialized constant Sass::Util::VLQ_BASE_SHIFT
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:1151: warning: previous definition of VLQ_BASE_SHIFT was here
/home/kontiky/my_blog/vendor/bundle/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:1152: warning: already initialized constant Sass::Util::VLQ_BASE
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:1152: warning: previous definition of VLQ_BASE was here
/home/kontiky/my_blog/vendor/bundle/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:1153: warning: already initialized constant Sass::Util::VLQ_BASE_MASK
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:1153: warning: previous definition of VLQ_BASE_MASK was here
/home/kontiky/my_blog/vendor/bundle/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:1154: warning: already initialized constant Sass::Util::VLQ_CONTINUATION_BIT
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:1154: warning: previous definition of VLQ_CONTINUATION_BIT was here
/home/kontiky/my_blog/vendor/bundle/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:1156: warning: already initialized constant Sass::Util::BASE64_DIGITS
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:1156: warning: previous definition of BASE64_DIGITS was here
/home/kontiky/my_blog/vendor/bundle/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:1157: warning: already initialized constant Sass::Util::BASE64_DIGIT_MAP
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:1157: warning: previous definition of BASE64_DIGIT_MAP was here
/home/kontiky/my_blog/vendor/bundle/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:1193: warning: already initialized constant Sass::Util::URI_ESCAPE
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:1193: warning: previous definition of URI_ESCAPE was here
/home/kontiky/my_blog/vendor/bundle/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:1237: warning: already initialized constant Sass::Util::ATOMIC_WRITE_MUTEX
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24/lib/sass/util.rb:1237: warning: previous definition of ATOMIC_WRITE_MUTEX was here
jekyll 3.5.0 | Error:  superclass mismatch for class Mapping
```

Could you, please, help me avoid these warnings and errors?

Comment: I have the exact same issue for jekyll 3.5.1 and ruby 2.3.0...
Haven't found any fix yet :(

Comment: Since I encountered the problem, too, I've [submitted a PR to update the documentation](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/6274).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and I finally decided to install Ruby on Windows without *Bash On Ubuntu* from this installer: https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

After that, I installed `jekyll` & `bundler` and, to make `jekyll` command-line script work, I had to execute this via `bundle`:

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve --watch
```